# Do $3\times3$ matrices with this multiplication property exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

I'm doing some novice exploration in what I think is basic abstract algebra and for curiosity reasons, I'm trying to find a matrix representation similar to $a+bi\cong\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ for the complex numbers, for some elements that multiply like this: $$\mathbf{e}_a\cdot\mathbf{e}_b = \mathbf{e}_{(2b-a)\text{ mod }3}$$
That is, there are 3 basis elements that we could call $\mathbf{i}, \mathbf{j}, \mathbf{k}$, each of which are idempotent, but when one is multiplied by another, it results in the third. For example, $\mathbf{i}^2 = \mathbf{i} = \mathbf{jk}$.

I've tried a couple of different matrix "representations" but the product hasn't matched my expectation for the equivalent entries. Does such a representation exist?

Comment: This isn’t an answer, but you should take a look at the quaternions.

Comment: I've found that there are matrix representations for such numbers (namely: $a\mathbf{i}+b\mathbf{j}+c\mathbf{k}\cong\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b&c\\c&a&b\\b&c&a\end{smallmatrix}\right)$). However, the multiplication isn't equivalent to a straight matrix product. Rather, it's the transpose of the product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your multiplication is associative (as it will be for matrices) then
$$
k = k^2 = (ij)k = i(jk) = i^2 = i .
$$

Comment: Is this only a problem if I'm trying to find a matrix representation, or would I be able to just say the operation isn't associative and still have a valid structure (disregarding matrices)?

Comment: @bjshnog I don't know. Play around, using associativity and the distributive law to look for a possible problem. I suspect that any such scheme will eventually.lead you to the quaternions. That's what Hamilton concluded. If you abandon associativity and thus matrices you can probably do anything you like and construct some kind of "algebra" but it's not likely to be useful.